# getResource("xmlfile.xml") throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have `xmlfile.xml` in `/WebContent/WEB-INF` folder of my web project.

I'm trying to get the path of this file using;

```
 URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("xmlfile.xml");
 String filePath = url.getFile();
```

But it's throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException` in second line of code.

What is the reason for this? The file is available as `WebContent/WEB-INF/xmlfile.xml`

Comment: What if you try "/xmlfile.xml".

Comment: Try placing it in the root directory of all the classes, which is ``/WEB-INF/classes/``.

Comment: Thats not working. What about web.xml? 
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("web.xml"); also throwing NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) for this :

```
ServletContext context = .... // get the context here
InputStream resourceContent = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/xmlfile.xml");
```

Or to get the real path :

```
String realPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/xmlfile.xml");
```

Remember, a Java EE webapp is a single (WAR) file, and therefore file system access to components within the WAR is not guaranteed. You can access objects using the standard Java class loader mechanism, but that won't give access to any paths of the WAR that aren't in the WAR's class path (*WEB-INF/classes and the WEB-INF/lib jars*).  Hence it fails in your case.

Comment: My class is not a servlet class. I want it in normal java class itself.

Comment: @Aneesh Then put the file in classpath , probably `WEB-INF/classes` or pass your method a reference to `ServletContext` !

Comment: Its working if I copied files in to WEB-INF/classes. But not working if I am trying to access a REST API using one client.
Why its not automatically copying myxml.xml to WEB-INF/classes which exists in "WEB-INF/myxml.xml" while deploying using tomcat?

Comment: @Aneesh Why should it automatically copy ?

Comment: Why it is omitting only myxml.xml? Its copying web.xml correctly. web.xm also resides in WEB-INF.

Comment: How did you build it ?

Comment: Running from  eclipse IDE. build folder creates at that time.

Comment: Copying myxml.xml into WEB-INF/classes works perfectly in normal cases. The problem coming only when I am trying to consume a REST API(here I am trying to get the path of myxml.xml), this time its again throwing NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource();` uses path relative to classpath root.
2. If your application is packaged as a jar/war use `getResourceAsStream()`.

So in short, make sure your resource is on classpath and use getResourceAsStream() instead.